# Asset based transfer Solidity Contract

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, blockchain

I am trying to create asset based transfer Smart contract by solidity language. i'm using ethereum.

**functions are**

1. Create assets (land_id, land_size, land_price) with a ownership of  contract owner.
2. Transfer assets to other person.
3. getCurrentOwnership
4. Previous Owners list
5. getAsset details.

**My Contract:**

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0; 

contract Asset {

uint256 public owners_count;
address public contract_owner;              // Manufacturer/owner
bytes32 public land_id;                   // land_id
bytes32 public land_sqrfeet;              // land_sqrfeet
bytes32 public land_created_date;         // Created date
mapping(uint => address) public owners;     // list of owners

function createland(bytes32 _land_id, bytes32 _land_sqrfeet, bytes32 _land_created_date) public returns (bool){
    setOwner(msg.sender);
    land_id = _land_id;
    land_sqrfeet = _land_sqrfeet;
    land_created_date = _land_created_date;
    return true;
}

//Modifier that only allows owner of the bag to Smart Contract AKA Good to use the function
modifier onlyOwner(){
    require(msg.sender == contract_owner);
    _;
}

//This function transfer ownership of contract from one entity to another
function transferOwnership(address _newOwner) public onlyOwner(){
    require(_newOwner != address(0));
    contract_owner = _newOwner;
}

//Get the previous owner in the mappings
function previousOwner() view public returns(address){
    if(owners_count != 0){
        uint256 previous_owner = owners_count - 1;
        return owners[previous_owner];
    }
}

function setOwner(address owner)public{
    owners_count += 1 ;
    owners[owners_count] = owner;
}

function getCurrentOwner() view public returns(address){
    return owners[owners_count] ;
}

function getOwnerCount() view public returns(uint256){
    return owners_count;
}}
```

but with this contract, i can able to get last created asset details. I can not get previous creation assets details.

**Questions are:**

1. Each Assets should be different contract address or one contract address?
2. If take one contract address for all assets, how can i get old transaction by contract function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Each Assets should be different contract address or one contract address?

> **Ans : Each Assets should be on one contract address only.**

2. If take one contract address for all assets, how can i get old transaction by contract function?

> **Ans : You can use structure(Data Structure) for store your all
>   assets details and also for get details.** You can see this [link for
>   how to create structure](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/how-to-create-a-data-structure-in-solidity-with-no-limits-on-size) .

Comment: hi mahesh rajput, thanks for reply. Let me try this. And few more questions:  i can create two assets with same details one by one. So it is creating duplicate record in the blockchain network. how can i restrict duplicate asset creation?

Comment: For that, you can add a new condition that checks whether the entered details of a structure is already existing or not in your asset structure.

Comment: thanks dude. can i get direct chat? i want to get more details regarding smart contract.

Comment: You can connect me over LinkedIn. You can find my LinkedIn profile under the About Me section of this profile.

Comment: hi dude, Can you please give suggestion to this contract https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/64231/suggestion-on-my-asset-contract.